# Error CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Tags: c#

How to fix this error?

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0,
>   Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies.

Comment: Have you made sure the dll is referenced correctly in your `References`, and that copy local is set to true?

Comment: Already Installed CRRedist*.msi still got this error

Comment: Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required. Please go to businessobjects.com/support for more information. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Crystal on the server using the provided msi for the vs2008 version...

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5\CRRedist2008_x86.msi
```

Installing this will add the required CR assemblies to the GAC. You should not add them to your app's bin folder.

Comment: Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Source Error: 


Line 181:        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
Line 182:        da.Fill(datatable);
Line 183:        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument(); // creating object of crystal report
Line 184:        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Sample.rpt")); // path of report 
Line 185:        crystalReport.SetDataSource(datatable); // binding datatable

Comment: After I click the button for displaying crystal report

Comment: Did you install the Crystal report viewer and make sure that data is on the data table. Please share the code with me .Is Sample.rpt is available at specified path

Comment: string conn = "data source=192.168.10.8,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=AttendanceLog;user=sa;password=p@$$w0rd";
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conn);

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_Userlogs", scon);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", useridlbl.Text);
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
da.Fill(datatable);
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Sample.rpt"));
crystalReport.SetDataSource(datatable);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;